# How to allow my Mac OS X 10.10.4 to download from sourceforge.net?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, homebrew

I'm trying to install QUCS(Quite Universal Circuit Simulator) to my Macbook.  Following link, http://qucs.sourceforge.net/build.html , I used Homebrew and follow the instructions in the section, Build instructions for MacOS,   I got an error msg saying:

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "adms"
Download failed: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mot-adms/adms-source/2.3/adms-2.3.4.tar.gz?r=&ts=1437800272

After some investigation, I found out my Mac doesn't allow me to download any types of files from source.net.  Although I changed my preferences in "Security & Privacy" to "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere," but it doesn't help.   I also turned off my firewall, but nothing changed.   Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: "404 Not Found Error" has nothing to do with your security settings, that's the server (downloads.sourceforge.net) giving an error that it doesn't have anything by that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceForge is having issues right now. Others are having trouble downloading also. You may end up having to request the author upload the binaries to another source.

I am pretty sure if it was an issue with your configuration, you'd still be able to download just not run, or not have access to the internet at all.